# How to deference a pointer to a pointer on the heap?

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble dereferencing a pointer to a pointer.  I have a node `e` that I put onto the heap and also another node called `List`.  `List` is a pointer pointing to `e`.

For some reason I am having a segmentation fault when I am dereferencing `e` through `List`:

```
struct ELEMENT{
    int key;
    int edge;
    struct ELEMENT *adjList;
};

int numOfNodes = 3; 

struct ELEMENT *e = (ELEMENT*)malloc(numOfNodes * sizeof(struct ELEMENT));
// e is now on the heap

struct ELEMENT **List = (ELEMENT**)malloc(numOfNodes * sizeof(struct ELEMENT));
// List (pointer to e) is now on the Heap

List[1]->key = 5;  // segmentation fault occurs here
```

Comment: C or C++? Which one?

Comment: In C [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Dereferencing is correct, allocation is wrong. Where does `List[1]` point to?

Comment: You have two mallocs that are the same size, why is one `ELEMENT *` and the other is `ELEMENT **`?

Comment: In general, if you use `N * sizeof (<type>)` in the `malloc()` argument, then the result is `<type> *`. It's always one more `*` in the pointer type than the argument to `sizeof`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already noticed you don't want a second `malloc`. You simply want `List` to point to `e` so all you need is to assign the "address of"  `e` to `list`.

```
struct ELEMENT **List = &e;
```

Besides that the way you try to access elements using `List` is wrong. Look at it like this:

- `e[n]` will access struct ELEMENT at index n
- `*List` is the same `e`
- So to access elements in the array you'll need `(*List)[n]`
- and to access a member you'll need `(*List)[n].key`

BTW: None of your `... malloc....` can compile as you have forgotten `struct` in the cast but instead of adding `struct`just remove the cast. Like:

```
struct ELEMENT *e =  malloc(numOfNodes * sizeof *e);
                    ^                           ^^
                no cast                    use dereferenced pointer to calculate size
```

With these changes your complete code will be:

```
struct ELEMENT{
    int key;
    int edge;
    struct ELEMENT *adjList;
};

int numOfNodes = 3; 

struct ELEMENT *e = malloc(numOfNodes * sizeof *e);
struct ELEMENT **List = &e;
(*List)[1].key = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `List` should be pointing to `e`, then you should not call `malloc()` again. You should do:

```
struct ELEMENT **List = &e;
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line

```
struct ELEMENT *e = (struct ELEMENT*)malloc(numOfNodes * sizeof(struct ELEMENT));
```

you don't just allocate memory for `struct ELEMENT` variable but you create an array with size 3 and type `struct ELEMENT`.

But as i understand by your code you want to create a List and add variable `e`. This can be done like that

```
struct ELEMENT **List = malloc(numOfNodes * sizeof(struct ELEMENT*));   //This allocate memory for 3 pointers, List[i] is type struct ELEMENT *
```

After you can allocate memory for each pointer like that

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < numOfNodes; i++)
{
    List[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct ELEMENT));   //here allocate memory for each pointer, for now each List[i] is type struct ELEMENT
}
```

So can change the declaration of `e` to `struct ELEMENT *e = malloc(sizeof(struct ELEMENT));`

and use `e` as you want for example

```
e->adjList = NULL;
e->edge = 5;
e->key = 15;
```

And add it to `List`

```
List[i] = e;
```

If you just want a pointer to reference at variable `e` you can use `struct ELEMENT **List = &e;` or more simple `struct ELEMENT *p_elem = e;`. So you can use these pointers to change the value of `e` members.

Don't forget to `free` the memory that previous allocated.

Hope this solve you any conclusions.